# How to send e-mails to addresses specified in issue/issue comments with post-commit githooks?

Tags: git, email, gitlab, githooks

It's been a while now I try to find hints on how to do it but I think I need some help to set me on tracks. Here's the situation :

For my company, it is very important to keep the customers updated with any possible news about the progress made on the development of the features they asked. However, our current process is not as efficient as it should, for the support team has to manually crawl the issues on GitLab to know what development status the features are in, and have then to call the customers on by one. Not cool.

The idea would be then to use Git hooks to automatically send e-mails to customers after commits and/or merge ; I would have the e-mail addresses in the issue or in the issue's comments.

I've been looking through Git hooks documentation and found out how to send e-mails to the team, but that's obviously not so close to what I want. So :

- **is this possible to achieve** ?
- if so, is there any tutorial, specific documentation that I missed out and you could advise me to explore ?
- any complementary advice or example would be more than welcome :)

Thanks for the forthcoming help :)

**EDIT** : After digging a little deeper, it appears GitLab [Web hooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md) would be more appropriated to my purpose and easier to set up. Problem solved !

Comment: "I've been looking through Git hooks documentation and found out how to send e-mails to the team, but that's obviously not so close to what I want." What more do you want to know?

Comment: Actually, I have absolutely no clue on how I can access/parse the content of the issue's comments to get the email addresses I'm supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

A hook could utilise the Gitlab API to implement this use case. For example, see the API calls to GET an [issue's details](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html#single-issue), as well as the API to return the issue's [comments/notes](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/notes.html#list-project-issue-notes.).

Hope that helps!